# Unique key prop still receiving unique key error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, key

I'm attempting to lay out a list after going through a for loop. I know I have to give each child in a component a "unique 'key' prop", but no matter how I give the key prop, I keep getting the error. The key is unique, is set on the outermost component, and is a string, but I still get the "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" error notification.

for loop

```
const ShowList = () => {
        let newList = []

        for (let i = 0; i < ListItems.length; i++) {
            newList.push(
                <>
                    <ListingItems
                        unit={ListItems[i]}
                        key={ListItems[i]}
                    />
                </>
            )
        }
        return newList;
    }
```

ListingItems component

```
const ListingItems = ({ unit }) => {

    return (
        <>
            <Text h4 style={[styles.MainText, { color: FontColor }]}>
                {unit}
            </Text>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the fragment `<>` since in your particular case it's redundant or replace it with `<React.Fragment` and assign a key to it.

```
<React.Fragment key={i}>
```